# SQL Azure, i should remove 'SELECT INTO', but how to make this query works?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have this query that i should make it run on SQL Azure.

```
WITH    RecursiveTable ( [OrganizationUnitID] )
              AS ( SELECT   OrganizationUnitID
                   FROM     OrganizationUnit AS ou ,
                            OrganizationUnitDefinition oud
                   WHERE    ( ParentOrganizationUnitID IN (
                              SELECT    val
                              FROM      CustomSPLIT(@strOUs, ',') )
                              OR OrganizationUnitID IN (
                              SELECT    val
                              FROM      CustomSPLIT(@strOUs, ',') )
                            )
                            AND ( ou.OrganizationUnitDefinitionID = oud.OrganizationUnitDefinitionID )
                   UNION ALL
                   ( SELECT ou.OrganizationUnitID
                     FROM   OrganizationUnit AS ou
                            INNER JOIN RecursiveTable AS rt ON ou.ParentOrganizationUnitID = rt.OrganizationUnitID ,
                            OrganizationUnitDefinition AS oud
                     WHERE  ou.OrganizationUnitDefinitionID = oud.OrganizationUnitDefinitionID
                   )
                 )
        SELECT DISTINCT                 -- this 
                [OrganizationUnitID]    -- won't work 
        INTO    #tempEmployeeByOUIDs    -- on azure
        FROM    RecursiveTable
```

knowing that the 'SELECT INTO' won't work on Azure, i modified it as the below, but it is giving me the following

> Incorrect syntax near 'RecursiveTable'.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ([OrganizationUnitID] CHAR(36))
        --DROP TABLE #temp
        INSERT INTO #temp
        WITH    RecursiveTable ( [OrganizationUnitID] )
                  AS ( SELECT   OrganizationUnitID
                       FROM     OrganizationUnit AS ou ,
                                OrganizationUnitDefinition oud
                       WHERE    ( ParentOrganizationUnitID IN (
                                  SELECT    val
                                  FROM      CustomSPLIT(@strOUs, ',') )
                                  OR OrganizationUnitID IN (
                                  SELECT    val
                                  FROM      CustomSPLIT(@strOUs, ',') )
                                )
                                AND ( ou.OrganizationUnitDefinitionID = oud.OrganizationUnitDefinitionID )
                       UNION ALL
                       ( SELECT ou.OrganizationUnitID
                         FROM   OrganizationUnit AS ou
                                INNER JOIN RecursiveTable AS rt ON ou.ParentOrganizationUnitID = rt.OrganizationUnitID ,
                                OrganizationUnitDefinition AS oud
                         WHERE  ou.OrganizationUnitDefinitionID = oud.OrganizationUnitDefinitionID
                       )
                     )
            SELECT DISTINCT
                    [OrganizationUnitID]
            --INTO    #tempEmployeeByOUIDs
            FROM    RecursiveTable
```

did i missed something??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ([OrganizationUnitID] CHAR(36))
        --DROP TABLE #temp
        ;WITH    RecursiveTable ( [OrganizationUnitID] )
                  AS ( SELECT   OrganizationUnitID
                       FROM     OrganizationUnit AS ou ,
                                OrganizationUnitDefinition oud
                       WHERE    ( ParentOrganizationUnitID IN (
                                  SELECT    val
                                  FROM      CustomSPLIT(@strOUs, ',') )
                                  OR OrganizationUnitID IN (
                                  SELECT    val
                                  FROM      CustomSPLIT(@strOUs, ',') )
                                )
                                AND ( ou.OrganizationUnitDefinitionID = oud.OrganizationUnitDefinitionID )
                       UNION ALL
                       ( SELECT ou.OrganizationUnitID
                         FROM   OrganizationUnit AS ou
                                INNER JOIN RecursiveTable AS rt ON ou.ParentOrganizationUnitID = rt.OrganizationUnitID ,
                                OrganizationUnitDefinition AS oud
                         WHERE  ou.OrganizationUnitDefinitionID = oud.OrganizationUnitDefinitionID
                       )
                     )
        INSERT INTO #temp
            SELECT DISTINCT
                    [OrganizationUnitID]
            --INTO    #tempEmployeeByOUIDs
            FROM    RecursiveTable
```

The `WITH` that introduces a CTE has to be the first part of the statement it is a part of, it has to come *before* the `INSERT`.